# how to make a search query using stored procedure in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a stored procedure for search query in my database in a specified table(books). I am having a problem whenever i execute the SP, there were no results. How can i solve this? any help please..

here(GUI):

```
Routine name: Search
type: procedure
parameters: direction(IN), Name(btitle), type(varchar), length(40)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%btitle%';
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded inside strings, so you're searching for books whose title contains the literal string `btitle`. You need to use `CONCAT` to concatenate the variable value:

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', btitle, '%');
```